# Obtaining untyped pointers to procedures

Tags: freepascal

I'd like to be able to obtain untyped pointers to functions/procedures while in {$MODE FPC} so code illustrated by the following example can work instead of getting an "Incompatible types" error, anyone know how?

```
program Project1;

{$MODE FPC}
{$MODESWITCH POINTERTOPROCVAR ON} // doesn't stop error
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} // doesn't stop error

function new_getmem(asize:longint):pointer;
begin
 new_getmem:=nil;
end;

var
 mem_mgr_new:tmemorymanager;

begin
 mem_mgr_new.GetMem:=@new_getmem;          // Error: Incompatible types...
 pointer(mem_mgr_new.GetMem):=@new_getmem; // both those work but I'd prefer the
 mem_mgr_new.GetMem:=pointer(@new_getmem); // clean code of the line that doesn't work
end.
```

EDIT:
 There used to be an answer below that answered this properly, but it went away. The discussion allowed me to find out that both {$MODESWITCH CLASSICPROCVARS ON} and {$MODESWITCH POINTERTOPROCVAR ON} need to be specified for the desired line to compile, but like was explained, this opens up lots of possibilities for errors, so use with care only when necessary.

Comment: Just making the compiler satisfied is not a good strategy. The problem here was in the `GetMem` function prototype mismatch. It should have been declared as `function new_getmem(Size: PtrUInt): Pointer;`.

Comment: Agreed TLama, this is a work around that can be useful for simulating overloading or a handful of other cases but the example I provided in the question is a terrible example where it shouldn't be used. Apologies for choosing such a bad and unrepresentative example.

Comment: I've editted the "EDIT:". Modeswitches do not require an "ON", as indicated in the original source. I've left the source as is, because the answer is what matters. See: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.2.0/prog/progsu106.html